# Запрет на закрытие программы

Tags: c++

Нужно запретить пользователю выходить из программы "крестиком"

Программа пишется под linux и windows.

Под windows есть:

```
EnableMenuItem(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), FALSE), SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_GRAYED);
```

А вот как с linux быть?

P.S. Если выложите кроссплатформенный способ - будет вообще шикос!

Comment: Из консольной программы? о_О

Comment: Под линуксом, не прокатит) там есть xkill, я бы рофлил вас, нажимая рядом с крестиком)) лел

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk я не говорю о том, чтобы удалить все способы закрытия программы. Я говорю о защите "От дурака"

Comment: `kill -9 'pidof youprogrammname'` спасет пользователя от вашей программы :)

Comment: Хотите на свою голову проклятий  от людей, которым не нравится нестандартное поведение программ?

Comment: @0-Level UNIX Monk: Заявлениями подобного рода разбрасываются как правило они самые, которых "в юниксах вообще нет". В реальности же современная разработка - это в большой части разгребание того трэшака, который наплодили те самые юниксовые дураки еще со времен динозавров.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для кроссплатформенного решения лучше взять [Qt](https://www.qt.io/).

Там для главного окна приложения переопределить член-функцию `closeEvent` следующим образом:

```
    void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) {
        //событие вызывается при клацанье на крестик. Перехватываем и игнорируем его
        event->ignore(); 
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо! Правда, не знаю как это переделать под консольное приложения...

Answer (score 0):

В Linux это нецелесообразно, так как пользователь может написать в терминале `xkill` и убить программу, нажав на любую область окна вашей программы!

Comment: Что такое "окно вашей программы", когда речь явно идет о "консольном" приложении?

Comment: В каком месте  речь идёт о консольном приложении? Покажите мне!

Comment: А, точно! Консольное! Ну какая разница? Как давно консоль перестала быть "окном программы"?

Comment: Окно терминала - это окно совсем другой программы. Никто вам не запрещает сделать `disown` на запущенный через окно терминала процесс. После этого вы можете смело убивать окно терминала чем угодно - процесс будет продолжать выполняться как ни в чем ни бывало.

Comment: Зачем все эти сложности, если в линуксах можно запустить программу вообще подальше от глаз пользуватиля, чтобы у него  не было соблазна убить?!